# ValueError: object arrays are not supported

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have created a matrix with 100 columns from a text file by counting the value ":READ" out of 100 entries. ie: vector[0][0] = number of :READ in first 100 entries in the file, vector[0][1]= number of :READin next 100 entries in the file and so on using the following code  
`

```
for i in range(start,len(df1),100):

df2=df1.iloc[start:end,]

count=df2.str.count(":READ").sum()
vector[p].append(count)

filewriter.writerow([start, count])
start=end
end=end+100
if(q<window):
    q=q+1
else: 
    q=0
    p=p+1
    vector.append([])
```

and when I use it to calculate eigen values,

```
e_vals, e_vecs = LA.eig(vector)
```

It gave the following error

> ValueError: object arrays are not supported

what could be done? i am not good in python coding.

Comment: fix your indentation - that matters for python code.-

Comment: Vector is clearly not a numpy 2D array (otherwise you can't append to a vector row). You don't show the actual creation of `vector`; perhaps you should. It should be something like `vector = np.empty((100, 100), dtype=np.float)`, assuming it's a square matrix.

Comment: i just used vector = [].. as the number of rows are dynamic. (depends on the size of input file)

Comment: `eig` tries to make an array from your list.  Apparently the result is an object dtype.  That could be because the sublists of `vector` differ in length.  Try `np.array(vector)` and examine the results.

Comment: i used {vector1-NP.array(vector)} . when i printed {vector1.shape} it gave 44 . not shape of a two dimensionalm array.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the type of the elements, with a simple

```
print(type(vector[0][0]))
```

I was having the same error, and in my case, all my elements were:

```
<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>
```

After converting every element to float with:

```
for i in range(len(vector)):
     for j in range(len(vector[i]):
          vector[i][j] = float(vector[i][j])
```

I got the results I wanted.